# How to make Hadoop servers listening on all IPs

Tags: java, hadoop, ip, protocols, master-slave

I'm learning to deploy Hadoop Cluster on 2 machines, one master and one slave. However, after deployment the web app server(i.e. port `8088` on master) is not reachable. I use `netstat -ant` to check it says like below:

```
proto  Recv-Q  Send-Q  LocalAddress    ForeignAddress  State
...
tcp         0       0  127.0.0.1:8088  *:*             LISTEN
tcp         0       0  0.0.0.0:56666   *:*             LISTEN
...
```

Other servers established by myself, like the one listening on port `56666`, are reachable. I think it maybe the problem that Hadoop web app server is only listening on `localhost` instead of any IP addresses.

Is it the true reason? Can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the parameter `yarn.resourcemanager.bind-host` to `0.0.0.0` in yarn-site.xml.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

1. Turn off iptables (Firewall)
2. Disable SELINUX

Then try