# How to configure HDFS to listen to 0.0.0.0

Tags: hadoop

I have an hdfs cluster listening on `192.168.50.1:9000` which means it only accepts connections via that IP. I would like it to listen at `0.0.0.0:9000`. When I enter `127.0.0.1 localhost master` in the `/etc/hosts`, then it starts at `127.0.0.1:9000`, which prevents all nodes to connect.

This question is similar to this one [How to make Hadoop servers listening on all IPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171725/how-to-make-hadoop-servers-listening-on-all-ips), but for hdfs, not yarn.

Is there an equivalent setting for `core-site.xml` like `yarn.resourcemanager.bind-host` or any other way to configure this? If not, then what's the reasoning behind this? Is it a security feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the NameNode you need to set these to `0.0.0.0` in your hdfs-site.xml:

- `dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host`
- `dfs.namenode.servicerpc-bind-host`
- `dfs.namenode.lifeline.rpc-bind-host`
- `dfs.namenode.http-bind-host`
- `dfs.namenode.https-bind-host`

The DataNodes use `0.0.0.0` by default.

If you ever need to find a config variable for HDFS, refer to [hdfs-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml).

Also very useful, if you look at any of the official Hadoop docs, at the bottom left corner of the page are all the default values for the various XML files.

[image]

So you can go to [Apache Hadoop 2.8.0](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/index.html) or your specific version and find the settings you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well the question is quite old already, however, usually you do not need to configure the bind address 0.0.0.0 because it is the default value! You'd rather have an entry in the `/etc/hosts` file `127.0.0.1 hostname` which hadoop resolves to 127.0.0.1.
Consequently you need to remove that entry and hadoop will bind to all interfaces (0.0.0.0) without any additional config entries in the config files.